# Progress cursor not seen on iPad

Tags: css, ajax, cursor

I'm coding a website and trying to work out best practise for displaying a progress cursor. As my site is using an Ajax request to do the main heavy lifting, I've simply selected the "progress cursor" in CSS and apply it via jQuery at the start of my Ajax request and set it back to cursor:auto by applying another class with jQuery when I get the response back. Now this works well on my PC and laptops, but does not seem to work on my iPad. Everything works fine but the cursor on the iPad does not change when the Ajax request fires. Has anyone had a similar 'problem' or am I missing something that needs to be done on iPad / Mac, or perhaps not doing this right?!

My CSS code to set cursor :
`body.wait { cursor: progress !important; }`

My jQuery to apply cursor at start of Ajax request

`$('html, body, button').css("cursor", "wait");`
..and to set it back on completion of request:
`$('html, body, button').css("cursor", "auto");`

Many thanks for any ideas of how to get it working on iPad!